# optimize the number of comparisons

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to optimize the code here.

```
if ns=='8':
    for i in nodes:
        if '02' == i[-2:]:
            d[i]='quorum-manager'
        if '05' == i[-2:]:
            d[i]='quorum-manager'
        if '06' == i[-2:]:
            d[i]='quorum-manager'
        if '09' == i[-2:]:
            d[i]='quorum-manager'
```

Above, `i` is a list of node names, for example:

```
i = ['xyz01', 'xyz02', 'xyz03', ...]
```

If the nodes end in `02` or `05` or `06` or `09`, I go ahead and replace the dictionary values for those specific node names.

Is it possible to have something like:

if node name ends in `02` or `05` or `06` or `09` replace the repective values in the dictionary in one shot instead of comparing in every line and then replacing

Comment: This one looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125124/more-efficient-use-of-python-dictionary

Comment: You're trying to optimize this code -- because profiling has told you that the comparisons are expensive? Don't try to optimize code without measuring.

Comment: It's not all about execution speed. Do improve your code when it's obviously repetitive and too verbose, as in this case. It matters a lot more than the millisecond you _might_ save if you run you code a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of strings that `i[-2:]` could be, just use the `in` operator:

```
if ns=='8':
    for i in nodes:
        if i[-2:] in ('02', '05', '06', '09'):
            d[i]='quorum-manager'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look up the last part of `i` in a set:

```
for i in nodes:
    if i[-2:] in {"02","05","06","09"}:
        d[i] = 'quorum-manager'
```

Searching repeatedly in a list (as in the other answers) is slow, and just poor practice in general. The brace notation `{...}` is supported for python 2.7 and later; you can also define a set like this: `set(["02","05","06","09"])`. If you'll be doing this a lot, you can make sets of the equivalent options in advance and use them repeatedly.

More general advice: if you have a number of *unrelated* tests that lead to the same action, you'd write a single `if` with several tests connected with `or`.

```
# Imaginary example
if i.endswith("02") or i.endswith("z03") or i[:2] == "xy":
    d[i]='quorum-manager'
```

Comment: use `{"02","05","06","09"}` in Python 3 and `("02","05","06","09")` in Python 2 instead, otherwise this is no optimization :D

Comment: Thanks. I went for explicitness, but might as well use the constant syntax. (Python 2.7+ required.)

Comment: in Python 2.7 `("02","05","06","09")` is faster because the peephole optimizer does not optimize `{"02","05","06","09"}` into constants.

Comment: I considered going into the "is it worth optimizing" issue in my answer, but decided it goes too far beyond the question. But no, it's not worth worrying about speed optimizations. The question, appropriately, was how to code something like this in a compact way.